# How do I show that the Cartesian product of two vertex-transitive graphs is vertex-transitive?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a way to prove this? Thanks for any assistance provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ and $H$ be your graphs.

If  $\varphi$ is an automorphism of $G$, then the map $\varphi':(g,h)\mapsto (\varphi(g),h)$ is an automorphism for $G\times H$.

Analogously if $\eta$ is an automorfism of $H$ then $\eta':(g,h)\mapsto (g,\varphi h)$ is an automorphism for $G\times H$.

To prove $G\times H$ is vertex-transitive you must pick arbitrary vertices $(g,h),(g',h')$ And prove there is an automorphism for $G\times H$ that sends $(g,h)$ to $(g',h')$.

This is easy, take $\varphi$ an automorphism on $G$ with $\varphi(g)=g'$ and an automorphsim $\eta$ on $H$ with $\eta(h)=h'$.

Notice that $\eta'(\varphi'(g,h))=\eta'(g',h)=(g',h')$. So $\eta'\circ\varphi'$ is the desired automorphism.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jorge!  That makes perfect sense.